# Enable Full Screen in Flutter Web Video Player using any Browser

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I have written a code for playing video in my Flutter Web application and it is playing the video in regular screen. Now I want to play it in full screen.

I have already tried different methods suggested here but nun of them is working. Please suggest a solution.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.url)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _controller.play();
          _controller.seekTo(_controller.value.position + widget.position);
        });
        Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1)).listen((_) {
          setState(() {
            _currentPosition = _controller.value.position;
          });
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _controller.value.isInitialized
              ? Stack(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Center(
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: VideoPlayer(_controller),//Video Player Implementation
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.08,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.84,
                    height: 80,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(_formatDuration(_currentPosition)),
                              Text(_formatDuration(
                                  _controller.value.duration)),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        VideoProgressIndicator(
                          _controller,
                          allowScrubbing: true,
                          colors: VideoProgressColors(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent.shade100,
                              bufferedColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
                              playedColor: Colors.blueAccent),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8,
                          height: 40,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _controller.value.isPlaying
                                          ? _controller.pause()
                                          : _controller.play();
                                    });
                                  },
                                  icon: _controller.value.isPlaying
                                      ? const Icon(
                                    Icons.pause_outlined,
                                    size: 30,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )
                                      : const Icon(
                                    Icons.play_arrow,
                                    size: 30,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        _controller.seekTo(Duration(
                                            seconds: _controller
                                                .value.position.inSeconds -
                                                10));
                                      },
                                      icon: const Icon(
                                        Icons.fast_rewind,
                                        size: 30,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 20,
                                  ),
                                  IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        _controller.seekTo(Duration(
                                            seconds: _controller
                                                .value.position.inSeconds +
                                                10));
                                      },
                                      icon: const Icon(
                                        Icons.fast_forward,
                                        size: 30,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          mikeOn = !mikeOn;
                                          _controller
                                              .setVolume(mikeOn ? 1.0 : 0.0);
                                        });
                                      },
                                      icon: mikeOn == true
                                          ? const Icon(
                                        CupertinoIcons.speaker_2_fill,
                                        size: 30,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )
                                          : const Icon(
                                        CupertinoIcons.speaker_slash_fill,
                                        size: 30,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 20,
                                  ),
                                  IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      },
                                      icon: const Icon(
                                        Icons.fullscreen_exit_sharp,
                                        size: 30,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )),
            ],
              )
              : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.lightGreen,),),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With above code video is getting played in browser full screen but not in the device full screen.